# What is the cleanest way to round a value to nearest 45 degrees?

Tags: language-agnostic, rounding

I have the same question as the question [here](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?757431-Best-way-to-round-a-value-to-nearest-45-degrees).

The user asked:

> I just wrote this to return the nearest 45 degree angle. Like 0, 45, 90, 135...
>
> It feels like there must be a better way of doing this though. This is working fine but it looks messy.

```
    public function nearestDeg(degs:int):int {
        
        if (degs >= 0 && degs <= 45) {
            if (degs <= 23) {
                return 0;
            }else {
                return 45;
            }
        }
        
        if (degs > 45 && degs <= 90) {
            if (degs <= 68) {
                return 45;
            }else {
                return 90;
            }
        }
        
        if (degs > 90 && degs <= 135) {
            if (degs <= 113) {
                return 90;
            }else {
                return 135;
            }
        }
                    
        if (degs > 135 && degs <= 180) {
            if (degs <= 158) {
                return 135;
            }else {
                return 180;
            }
        }
        
        if (degs > 180 && degs <= 225) {
            if (degs <= 203) {
                return 180;
            }else {
                return 225;
            }
        }
        
        if (degs > 225 && degs <= 270) {
            if (degs <= 248) {
                return 225;
            }else {
                return 270;
            }
        }
        
        if (degs > 270 && degs <= 315) {
            if (degs <= 293) {
                return 270;
            }else {
                return 315;
            }
        }
        
        if (degs > 315 && degs <= 360) {
            if (degs <= 338) {
                return 315;
            }else {
                return 360;
            }
        }
        
        
        return 0;
        
    }
```

What is the cleanest way to round a value to nearest 45 degrees?

Comment: Why the downvote? I didn't understand the answers [here](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?757431-Best-way-to-round-a-value-to-nearest-45-degrees).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd divide the value by 45°, round, and then multiply back by 45°. Pseudocode:

```
deg = round(deg / 45) * 45;
```

Assumption: the `/` operator returns a floating-point representation and does not perform integer division. If the specific language does not treat it like this it should be handled explicitly (e.g., you could divide by `45.0` instead of `45`).

Comment: In a decent language, when given two exact operands deg and 45, the / operator would create an exact fraction rather than falling back to an inexact floating point operation ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know OP asked for degrees, but radians may be helpful for others.

```
import numpy as np
round(radians/(np.pi/4))*np.pi/4
```